# sql group_concat version needed to grab column names

Tags: sql, group-concat

I have this line of code for mySQL but i need the SQL version of it, it gives me the column names of a table in one line seperated by a comma

```
select concat(column_name) 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='db_humanajsa' 
      and table_name='re627a';
```

Comment: What you mean by `SQL version`? MySql isn't sql?

Comment: Did my answer get you what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others in future to find the correct answer. If you don't know how to accept an answer, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server**

Since there is no `GROUP_CONCAT` in SQL Server, you can try this:

```
SELECT
      column_name = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10),T2.column_name)
          FROM information_schema.columns T2
          WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM information_schema.columns T1
ORDER BY column_name
```